# How to add font awesome icon to a svg circle drawn via svg.js?

Tags: svg, svg.js

I am using svg.js, Now I am stuck in a scenario where I need to add a font awesome icon to a svg circle.
I can pretty much add the icon through vanilla js. But for this purpose I want to use svg.js specifically.
For instance. I can find that svg.js have text.plain() && text.text() method which pretty much is printing the Unicode I am supplying (Though it is expected). So how should I create the icon in svg.js?
Any help will be highly appreciated!.
Actually I am looking for svg.js equivalent code for following code snippet.

```
 let text = document.createElementNS(SVGNamespace, 'text');
 text.classList.add(someClass);
 text.setAttribute('x', xCordinate);
 text.setAttribute('y', yCordinate);
 text.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
 text.setAttribute('fill', '#000');
 text.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
 text.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', 'middle');
 text.innerHTML = unicode; // This is the unicode for font awesome icon
```

On Css side I will have something as

```
.someClass{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Font Awesome icon in SVG? AFAIK you can not convert a unicode symbol in a font-set to SVG. But Font Awesome use to have a SVG version of their font.

Comment: Ha! I should have googled that. I found https://convertio.co/ttf-svg/ but I also checked font-awesome and you get SVGs from them

Comment: @r2alpha did my answer help you?

Comment: Thanks @dotnetCarpenter. Though actually I need to use unicode of font awesome icon instead of svg path of font awesome icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [downloaded the font-awesome zip file](https://fontawesome.com/download) and took the first icon I could find in `fontawesome-free-5.15.1-web.zip/fontawesome-free-5.15.1-web/svgs/brands/500px.svg`.
If you open `500px.svg` in your editor, you will find the `viewBox` attribute and a `<path>` element with a `d=""` attribute. Copy the `d` attribute which is the icon path. It is a bunch of commands and coordinates which fits inside the `viewBox`.

As you can see in the snippet below, I have used the `viewBox` to define my new SVG and the path `d` attribute to get svg.js to draw it.

```js
const fontAwesomeIcon = "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7 8.5-28.6 53 0 89.4-10.1 89.4-64.4 0-61-77.1-89.6-116.9-44.6-23.5 26.4-17.6 42.1-17.6 157.6 50.7 31 118.3 22 160.4-20.1 24.8-24.8 38.5-58 38.5-93 0-35.2-13.8-68.2-38.8-93.3-24.8-24.8-57.8-38.5-93.3-38.5s-68.8 13.8-93.5 38.5c-.3.3-16 16.5-21.2 23.9l-.5.6c-3.3 4.7-6.3 9.1-20.1 6.1-6.9-1.7-14.3-5.8-14.3-11.8V20c0-5 3.9-10.5 10.5-10.5h241.3c8.3 0 8.3 11.6 8.3 15.1 0 3.9 0 15.1-8.3 15.1H130.3v132.9h.3c104.2-109.8 282.8-36 282.8 108.9 0 178.1-244.8 220.3-310.1 62.8zm63.3-260.8c-.5 4.2 4.6 24.5 14.6 20.6C306 56.6 384 144.5 390.6 144.5c4.8 0 22.8-15.3 14.3-22.8-93.2-89-234.5-57-238.3-38.2zM393 414.7C283 524.6 94 475.5 61 310.5c0-12.2-30.4-7.4-28.9 3.3 24 173.4 246 256.9 381.6 121.3 6.9-7.8-12.6-28.4-20.7-20.4zM213.6 306.6c0 4 4.3 7.3 5.5 8.5 3 3 6.1 4.4 8.5 4.4 3.8 0 2.6.2 22.3-19.5 19.6 19.3 19.1 19.5 22.3 19.5 5.4 0 18.5-10.4 10.7-18.2L265.6 284l18.2-18.2c6.3-6.8-10.1-21.8-16.2-15.7L249.7 268c-18.6-18.8-18.4-19.5-21.5-19.5-5 0-18 11.7-12.4 17.3L234 284c-18.1 17.9-20.4 19.2-20.4 22.6z"

const canvas = SVG()
  .viewbox(0, 0, 448, 512) // set the viewBox to match font-awesome icon
  .size('100%', 300) // set any size you want
  .attr('id', 'canvas') // add an id or class so that you can style via CSS
  .addTo('body') // add the SVG to the <body> element

canvas.path(fontAwesomeIcon)  // draw the font-awesome icon
canvas.circle(512) // draw a cirle
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: white;
}
#canvas circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.16/svg.min.js"></script>
```

Of course you can move the icon around as well. I like the icon to be more centred in the circle so I added:

```js
canvas.path(fontAwesomeIcon)  // draw the font-awesome icon
  .scale(.85)
  .move(50,10)
```

I also added an `id` attribute to the SVG so that I easily can target the circle from CSS. You do not have to that but I like to do my styling in CSS. If you wanted to set the same style for the circle element without CSS, you could do `canvas.circle(512).stroke({ color: 'red', width: 5 }).fill('none')`.

CSS-Tricks got some more information about styling SVG elements in [their almanac](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke/).

Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks, for the solutions. Though It will be great if you can suggest some way to use unicode for displaying font awesome icon. Though I will be accepting the answer. I want to have a scenario where instead of using the font awesome svg path I can use the font awesome icon.

Comment: I need to do some research before but for the moment I do not have time. However, I have bookmarked your question and will get back to you when I have time again.